# Lotus Notes Client: How to create an Inbox view of only selected senders

Tags: lotus-notes

I'm really at a loss here, and my google-fu is failing me.

I am using Lotus Notes Client 8.5.3

In essence, I want to create an alternate view of my inbox, consisting only of emails received from  a defined set of users.   I'm looking for the simplest and most direct way to do this.   Ideally, I would "clone" the Inbox "view" , and add a restriction to it.

(I've already highlighted selected senders, but this is not enough, nor is sorting or searching within the mailbox).

I've tried to look at "Views" as the logical point for performing this task, but it seems to require a lot more manual work and learning /coding  than I want to invest.

Answer (score 1):

In Lotus Notes there are two different "mechanisms" to show documents: Views and Folders.

For you as a user they look the same, but they are completely different:

A view automatically shows documents, that match certain criteria. Whenever a document meets the criteria, it is automatically shown in the view.

A folder contains documents, that "someone" puts in them "manually" (more or less). For the Inbox- Folder that "someone" is the router task.

It is important to know, that only the folder "knows" which documents belong to it. The documents themselfes do NOT know, in which folder(s) they are displayed.

That means: you could create a view, that contains all documents from a specific sender by defining the following selection formula:

```
SELECT From = "sender@domain.com"
```

Or for multiple senders (or different formats of the same sender):

```
SELECT From = "sender1@domain.com" : "sender2@domain.net"
```

Or even less specific:

```
SELECT @Contains( @Lowercase( From ) ; "tim" )
```

For multiple users you can use the "or"- operator or use the power of list manipulation built into Formula language:

```
SELECT @Contains( @Lowercase( From ; "tim" ) | @Contains( @Lowercase( From ; "tom" )
```

Or (better):

```
SELECT @Contains( @Lowercase( From ; "tim" : "tom" : "paul" )
```

BUT you cannot add a condition like `& Folder = "($Inbox)"` as that information simply is not stored anywhere in the document.

I know, that the All- Documents- View contains a column with the name of the folder, but the command that renders it is only valid in Column Formulas and NOT in selection formulas. And in addition a column containing this formula is not even sortable or categorizable.

So the closest you can get is using my select- example above to get all mails from one sender and copy the design from the "All documents"- view to at least get a display of the containing folder.

Comment: Theoretically, a post-delivery agent could just add selected messages to an additional folder right after they are added to the Inbox by the router, but if creating a view is (in the OP's words) "a lot more manual work and learning /coding than I want to invest", then an agent is way more than that! And that's not even considering what it would take to remove them from the addition folder when they're deleted from the Inbox.

Comment: And the server admin has to allow agents, and you need to be able to write LotusScript- agents, etc., etc. This might be a solution for someone who knowswhatto do and has the right rights, but not for a "normal" user. And take into considerstion, that after every move to another folder an update has to occur as well...

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to write this up with more detail, but in the interim:   had trouble with the first two types of SELECTS, likely cause of all the weird variations on "From".    However, the third SELECT @Contains( @Lowercase( From ) ; "tim" )  is good enough for my purpose.   Can you help me with syntax for multiple users?   Tried several variations of "OR" conditionals to no avail on the whole @Contains but no dice. Thanks!

Comment: Check my edit, or = | , lists are concatenated using colon

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind selecting all of the people and hitting a button, you could make a custom toolbar button (file-->preferences-->toolbar-->customize) with the formula `@AddToFolder("Inbox2"; "")`